# WiFi website interface not working

Tags: wireless-networking

My home WiFi stopped working as I logged into 192.168.0.1 my WiFi web interface for parental control but by mistake clicked on disable WiFi access and now whole WiFi of the house is not working and this IP is not working as well I can’t open the website interface.... please help I have tried resetting it many many times and enable WiFi on my pc with Ethernet cable connection it still doesn’t work something to do with web interface enabling.

Comment: I have tried using Ethernet cable yesterday internet was working on my pc now it’s not.... I have tried to reset also but nothing is fixed

Comment: Please include your router brand-- if anything beyond your ISP is possible to gleam either from the hardware or from the admin interface. Also please note that most reset buttons require you to hold it for 5+ seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Get an Ethernet cable and plug your computer directly into your router and fix it, or reset your router and configure it back the way you need it to be.

If you need help resetting your router you can consult your router's manual (either the one that came with it or a copy online) for details.

Comment: In a scenario where OP may not have an Ethernet cable or device with an Ethernet port, resetting the router to factory defaults will fix the issue. Although this will discard custom SSID, PSK, and other custom entries such as static LAN IP addresses and forwarded port configurations, in my opinion its a small price to pay to regain internet access without access to the physical Ethernet port.

Comment: on a side note: if the user has a separate router and modem (not a combo one) and they are connected via Ethernet cable - the user can unplug the router from the modem and use that cable to plug directly into the router.

Comment: Yes, thats also true - never thought of that! Most routers come with at least 1 ethernet cable, as do standalone modems, so theres probably also one lying about in the routers box too. One thing I have personally seen in recent years is that some people dont have devices which physically connect using Ethernet anymore - some new "ultrabook" laptops dont have this capability, and phones obviously dont either (unless there is an ethernet dongle about). With larger bandwidth and faster WiFi speeds I see this becoming more commonplace in the consumer home, although its unlikely to be phased out..

Comment: I have tried resetting my router but still doesn’t work i have enabled my WiFi on pc with Ethernet Connection but it still doesn’t work

Comment: What kind of router do you have? By resetting I meant to push whatever reset button it has until it cycles through all of your lights - this should return it to factory defaults.

Comment: I have a small button to restart and pressed it for 30 seconds nothing happens swirled it off on several time nothing happened and unitymedia is provider I think I might have doable something on WiFi web interface with now the website is not working

Comment: What kind of router is it though? we might be able to walk you through it

Comment: It’s technicolor model tc7200.u

Comment: did you try connecting to 192.168.0.1 after you reset it? you should be able to login with the default username and password

Comment: Yes I tried but the website will not load it’s says can’t reach website

Comment: Thank you it did work

Comment: @PinkyVirk glad to hear it! also, don’t forget to accept the answer so the question will show up as solved.

Comment: some routers default to a different address - `192.168.1.1` for example.  One of mine has a factory address of `192.168.78.1`!  Alternatively, some routers will factory reset only when powered on _while_ the reset switch is held in.  Something to try.  @mael' I would suggest that you add "Consult your Router's manual for details on how to reset it" to your answer.

Comment: good suggestion - i'll add that wording. we confirmed his specific router defaults to the address he was trying though.